# Trying to extract gridview cell content of a different form in a textbox using if conditions. Not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, desktop-application

This is a csv file, source for the gridview.

```
Child(5-12),400,800,1050,1450,2200
Adult(>12),550,1000,1500,2100,2700
Group of 5,3000,5000,8000,12500,25000
Group of 10,5000,8000,15000,22000,40000
```

I have stored the cell contents of the gridview(TicketRateView) in a list.

```
 GlobalValues.UpdatedrateList = new List<Ticketpricerate>();

            for (int i=0; i<TicketRateView.Rows.Count; i++) 
            {
                Ticketpricerate rate = new Ticketpricerate();
                rate.Ticket_Category = TicketRateView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                rate.Rate_for_1hr = Convert.ToInt32(TicketRateView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                rate.Rate_for_2hr = Convert.ToInt32(TicketRateView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                rate.Rate_for_3hr = Convert.ToInt32(TicketRateView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                rate.Rate_for_4hr = Convert.ToInt32(TicketRateView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                rate.Rate_for_wholeday = Convert.ToInt32(TicketRateView.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                GlobalValues.UpdatedrateList.Add(rate);
            }
```

In a different form, i have a textbox named `staytime` where i will get the visitors stay time `in minutes`. Based on that information, i want to show the cell value in another textbox `pay_amount`. Like if the visitors stay time is 1 hr, then show e.g 400$ from the cell.

and here is what i have tried, it doesnt show anything.

```
private void Pay_amount_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            int timeofstay = Convert.ToInt32(visitorstaytime.Text);
            foreach (Ticketpricerate rate in GlobalValues.UpdatedrateList)
            {
                if (timeofstay == 60) 
                {
                    pay_amount.Text = rate.Rate_for_1hr.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your problem mark it as an acceptable answer. If it helps you give it an upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to query against Ticket_Category and time of stay. For condensed version of your code, read data into your class then set to the DataGridView.

I used `Child(5-12)` but that needs to have logic to determine which category to select e.g. perhaps from a ComboBox.

`ticketPriceRateList` becomes `GlobalValues.UpdatedrateList`. Then the loading of the DatagridView is of course in a different place along with the code to get the rate.

```
var fileName = "SomeFile.txt";
int timeofstay = Convert.ToInt32(visitorstaytime.Text);

List<Ticketpricerate> ticketPriceRateList = (
        from line in File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        where line.Length > 0
        let Items = line.Split(',')
        select new Ticketpricerate()
        {
            Ticket_Category = Items[0],
            Rate_for_1hr = Convert.ToInt32(Items[1]),
            Rate_for_2hr = Convert.ToInt32(Items[2]),
            Rate_for_3hr = Convert.ToInt32(Items[3]),
            Rate_for_4hr = Convert.ToInt32(Items[4]),
            Rate_for_wholeday = Convert.ToInt32(Items[5]),
        })
    .ToList();


int price = 0;
if (timeofstay == 60)
{
    price = ticketPriceRateList
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Ticket_Category == "Child(5-12)")
        .Rate_for_1hr;
} // more conditions


Console.WriteLine(price);
```

Comment: oh. thank you. I actually never even considered about the category part. I am going to try this. thank you again.